# Remove padding from body bottom in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**My Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>

/*RESET BLOCK START ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* RESET CODE END --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


body
{
    display:flex
    ;background-color:#20262b;min-height:100vh;
}

.column
{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    padding: 0;
    /* flex:1; */
}

/* .flexContainers{display:flex;} */
#body__
{
    
    background-color:#30364b;
    padding: 0;
}
#body___header
{
    /* display:flex; */
    background-color:#10561b;
}
#body___middleSection
{
    display:flex;
    flex:auto;
    background-color:#30363b;
}

#body___footer
{
    background-color:#10561b;
}


</style>
</head>
<body class="">
<div id="body__" class="column">
<div id="body___header" class="flexContainer"><span class="">This is Header of body</span></div>
<div id="body___middleSection" class="flexContainer"><span class="">This is cntnt of body</span></div>
<div id="body___footer" class="flexContainer"><span class="">This Footer of body</span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Layout

In the above code you can notice padding after "This Footer of body" content.

I don't understand where this padding is coming from.

Due to this padding the page is slightly vertical scroll-able ( at least in Firefox ), The page is not supposed to be scroll able unless there is extra content.

How can i fix this.

**EDIT**

Even if you run snippet here, you can notice its slightly scroll able (vertically) which is undesired behavior.

**EDIT 2**

Color of the slight space in the bottom is same as of **body tag**.
So i am assuming, its either **bottom padding of body** or **bottom margin of div with id body__**

Comment: Your snippet seems fine in Chrome, as far as I can tell, and I'm not seeing any scrollable content in Firefox.

Comment: i tested it in chrome(linux), its not scroll able  but padding is there.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "padding"? Which spacing is the problem?

Comment: slight space just below footer is the problem

Comment: I see it on chrome but isn't a real "padding". In firefox i can't see it. I resolve adding height: 100% on <html>.

Comment: Try right-clicking on the spacing and choose Inpect. That usually shows where the corresponding spacing is coming from.

Comment: @Geramno Plebani you cant see in firefox probably because its vertically scroll able, try to scroll it to check if its there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .header {
            background: green;
            height: 50px;
        }

        .middle-section {
            background: blue;
            height: calc(100% - 100px);
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        .footer {
            background: red;
            height: 50px;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div class="header">

        </div>
        <div class="middle-section">

        </div>
        <div class="footer">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you but what i want is the middle section to take up the remaining space,  which is not happening in your code. I tried it in firefox

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved

Initially i was using [reset.css](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Now i am using [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Though i still don't know what was causing this weird behavior